# Render random Iframe in a page with React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router

I am new to React and need help. I'm trying to create an application that shows an iframe slot at certain moments.

It will have to show advertisements, so the iframe will have to appear (for example before the video starts), but it will have to occupy only a portion of the screen.

How can I do this or how can I check the link to show in the slot?

Thanks a lot to those who try to help me.

This is my code, but it's very rude. I have only a button that reload the page, and an iframe in this page. With the button i want to reload only the iframe, and i want to show a different iframe for each reload.

```js
import React, {
  Component
} from "react";
import {
  render
} from "react-dom";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    index: 0
  };
  reload = () => {
    this.setState({
      index: this.state.index + 1
    });
  };
  render() {
    return ( <
      div >
      <
      button style = {
        {
          position: "absolute",
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          top: 500
        }
      }
      onClick = {
        this.reload
      } >
      Pubblicità <
      /button> <
      iframe style = {
        {
          position: "absolute",
          left: 500,
          right: 0,
          top: 10
        }
      }
      key = {
        this.state.index
      }
      title = "AdSlot 11"
      src = "https://viewm.moonicorn.network/#%7B%22options%22%3A%7B%22publisherAddr%22%3A%220x21cd5b5629ce4b0d42ea1c9ccd5cbb9b2aa99d1a%22%2C%22whitelistedToken%22%3A%220x89d24A6b4CcB1B6fAA2625fE562bDD9a23260359%22%2C%22whitelistedType%22%3A%22legacy_300x250%22%2C%22randomize%22%3Atrue%2C%22targeting%22%3A%5B%7B%22tag%22%3A%22blockchain%22%2C%22score%22%3A100%7D%2C%7B%22tag%22%3A%22ott%22%2C%22score%22%3A100%7D%2C%7B%22tag%22%3A%22pubblicit%C3%A0%204%22%2C%22score%22%3A100%7D%5D%2C%22width%22%3A%22300%22%2C%22height%22%3A%22250%22%2C%22minPerImpression%22%3A%220%22%2C%22minTargetingScore%22%3A%220%22%2C%22fallbackUnit%22%3Anull%2C%22marketSlot%22%3A%22QmTLsEBXAurLvqwH6CFCWgKssG8H8yo1ZN8HAZXjPFszUq%22%7D%7D"
      width = "300"
      height = "250"
      scrolling = "no" /
      >
      <
      /div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is the code obtained thanks to the help of warmachine:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import AdSlot1 from "./components/AdSlot1";
import AdSlot2 from "./components/AdSlot2";
import AdSlot3 from "./components/AdSlot3";
import AdSlot4 from "./components/AdSlot4";
import AdSlot5 from "./components/AdSlot5";
import AdSlot6 from "./components/AdSlot6";
import AdSlot7 from "./components/AdSlot7";
import AdSlot8 from "./components/AdSlot8";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    index: 0,
    iframeSrcs: [
      "/336x280/",
      "/300x100",
      "/300x250",
      "/160x600",
      "/180x150",
      "/234x60",
      "/468x60",
      "/250x250"
    ], //assuming they are stored in an array.
    visibility: false
  };
  reload = () => {
    const iframeLength = this.state.iframeSrcs.length;
    if (this.state.index < iframeLength) {
      this.setState({
        index: this.state.index + 1,
        visibility: true
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({ index: 0, visibility: true }); //starting again
    }
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({ visibility: false });
    }, 5000);
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/336x280/" component={AdSlot1} />
          <Route exact path="/300x100" component={AdSlot2} />
          <Route exact path="/300x250" component={AdSlot3} />
          <Route exact path="/160x600" component={AdSlot4} />
          <Route exact path="/180x150" component={AdSlot5} />
          <Route exact path="/234x60" component={AdSlot6} />
          <Route exact path="/468x60" component={AdSlot7} />
          <Route exact path="/250x250" component={AdSlot8} />
          <Route
            path="/pubblicità"
            children={({ match, location }) =>
              match && (
                <div>
                  <button
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      left: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      top: 500
                    }}
                    onClick={this.reload}
                  >
                    pubblicità
                  </button>
                  {this.state.visibility}
                  <iframe
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      left: 500,
                      right: 0,
                      top: 10
                    }}
                    key={this.state.index}
                    title="AdSlot"
                    src={this.state.iframeSrcs[this.state.index]}
                    height="100%"
                    width="100%"
                    scrolling="no"
                    frameborder="0"
                  />
                </div>
              )
            }
          />
        </div>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

Comment: can you provide codes?

Comment: I modified the question, inserting the code

Comment: each reload you want to change iframe src right?

Comment: exactly! I already have a series of iframes, and I would like to show them randomly.

Comment: these urls are you are storing in the same component in an array ?

Comment: For now, yes, but I'm open to suggestions. It would not be a problem to dedicate a component to each iframe if this simplifies the project.

Comment: check my answer once .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    import React, { Component} from "react";
    import {render} from "react-dom";

    class App extends Component {
      state = {
        index: 0,
        iframeSrcs:["https://...","https://..","http://....",........] //assuming they are stored in an array.
        visibility:false
      };
      reload = () => {
       const iframeLength=this.state.iframeSrcs.length
      if(thi.state.index<iframeLength){
        this.setState({
          index: this.state.index + 1,
          visibility:true
        });
      }else{
       this.setState({index:0,visibility:true})//starting again
      }
       setTimeout(() => {
       this.setState({visibility:false)}
       }, 5000);//for 5 sec after that it will hide
      }
      render() {
        return ( <
          div >
          <
          button style = {
            {
              position: "absolute",
              left: 0,
              right: 0,
              top: 500
            }
          }
          onClick = {
            this.reload
          } >
          Pubblicità <
          /button>{this.state.visibility? <
          iframe style = {
            {
              position: "absolute",
              left: 500,
              right: 0,
              top: 10
            }
          }
          key = {
            this.state.index
          }
          title = "AdSlot 11"
          src = {this.state.iframeSrcs[this.state.index]}
          width = "300"
          height = "250"
          scrolling = "no" /
          >:""}
          <
          /div>
        );
      }
    }

    export default App;
```

it will show different iframes on button click and cycle to first when you reach the end..Modified used setTimeout for hiding..check once and let me know

Comment: I tried the code but this error results:
./src/App.js
  Line 14:26:  'iframeSrcs' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: i forgot to add this.state in reload method

Comment: but populate with actual iframeSrcs

Comment: if I wanted to show the iframe only for a few seconds, 5 for example, and then I wanted it to disappear (to reappear at the next reload), how could I do?

Comment: i adjust the answer put a setTimeout in it try and let me know

Comment: I have tested it but the timeout seems not to have worked. Nothing has changed since the old application.

Comment: but it should hide

Comment: When I click the reload button, the iframe updates to show the next iframe. Nothing happens until I click the reload button again. If I click again, the iframe updates.
The application works the same way as before.
thanks for the time you are dedicating me!!

Comment: wait let me create a sandbox and get back to you

Comment: have add the condition i added before iframe??

Comment: Yes. If you are more comfortable I can add my code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
   <Router>
        <div>
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Route exact path="/336x280/" component={AdSlot1} />
          <Route exact path="/300x100" component={AdSlot2} />
          <Route exact path="/300x250" component={AdSlot3} />
          <Route exact path="/160x600" component={AdSlot4} />
          <Route exact path="/180x150" component={AdSlot5} />
          <Route exact path="/234x60" component={AdSlot6} />
          <Route exact path="/468x60" component={AdSlot7} />
          <Route exact path="/250x250" component={AdSlot8} />
          <Route
            path="/pubblicità"
            children={({ match, location }) =>
              match && (
                <div>
                  <button
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      left: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      top: 500
                    }}
                    onClick={this.reload}
                  >
                    pubblicità
                  </button>
                  {this.state.visibility?
                  <iframe
                    style={{
                      position: "absolute",
                      left: 500,
                      right: 0,
                      top: 10
                    }}
                    key={this.state.index}
                    title="AdSlot"
                    src={this.state.iframeSrcs[this.state.index]}
                    height="100%"
                    width="100%"
                    scrolling="no"
                    frameborder="0"
                  />:""}
                </div>
              )
            }
          />
        </div>
      </Router>
```

you are not applying the condition !!use this it will work i added the condition

Comment: ok, now works!!
You were really very kind. Without you I would never have achieved this. Thanks so much.

Comment: I have one last request. Is it possible to check the frame reload from another page? How could I do?

Comment: i dont understand the question ,elaborate please?

Comment: I would like to send the iframe reload signal, from another page if possible. So that on a page I would only have the iframe that reloads every time I click on the button (which is on a different route).
I hope I have been clearer.